# text format parsing error in line 1: invalid metric name when testing prometheus metrics using rest assured

Tags: prometheus, rest-assured, prometheus-pushgateway

I'm trying to mimic metrics in Prometheus using Push Gateway. When I'm passing these values in PostMan, I'm able to see the entry of metrics in Push Gateway. But, when I'm trying the same with Rest Assured, it is not working. I'm getting error as RESPONSE :text format parsing error in line 1: invalid metric name.

Anyone has any idea?

```
public void sendRequestsToPushGateway()  {
        System.out.println("Send request to Push Gateway");

        validatableResponse = given().contentType(ContentType.TEXT)
                .body("\"container_cpu_cfs_throttled_seconds_total\"" + "{" + "\"container_name\" = \"test\", "
                        + "\"pod_name\"=\"test-stable\"," + "\"exported_namespace\"=\"demo\"" + "} "
                        + "100.0\n")
                .when()
                .put("http://prometheus-pushgateway.eu-mesh-poc-aws.dev.io/metrics/job/cpusaturationtest/instance/3")
                .then();

        String RESPONSE = validatableResponse.extract().asString();
        System.out.println("RESPONSE :" + RESPONSE);
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

Given the code, the page content will be:

```
"container_cpu_cfs_throttled_seconds_total"{"container_name" = "test", "pod_name"="test-stable","exported_namespace"="demo"} 100.0
```

There are too many `"` and spaces. The content should be:

```
container_cpu_cfs_throttled_seconds_total{container_name="test",pod_name="test-stable",exported_namespace="demo"} 100.0
```

You can refer to the Prometheus [textfile format](https://prometheus.io/docs/instrumenting/exposition_formats/#line-format).

Comment: Thanks Michel. I realize that I have used to many " where it is not needed. Appreciate your quick response

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution. I have to remove extra "" from tags like container_name, pod_name & exported_namespace

```
validatableResponse = given().contentType(ContentType.TEXT)
                .body("container_cpu_cfs_throttled_seconds_total"
                        + "{container_name = \"test\", pod_name =\"test-stable\",exported_namespace=\"demo\"}"
                        + "100.0\n")
                .when()
                .put("http://prometheus-pushgateway.eu-mesh-poc-aws.dev.io/metrics/job/cpusaturationtest/instance/3")
                .then();
```